# Set password of new user in bash script on RedHat

Tags: bash

```
#! /bin/bash

C_PASS="12345"
echo "enter user name which u want to create"
read UNAME
UPASS="987654321"
echo $C_PASS | sudo -S -k useradd $UNAME

echo "$UPASS" | echo "$C_PASS" | sudo -S -k passwd --stdin "$UNAME"
```

i got error like:

```
[sudo] password for admin: Changing password for user zzzak.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

plzz help me.

Comment: `{ echo ...; echo ...; } | sudo ...` might work, but I would recommend against storing the root user's password in the script in the first place. Edit the `sudo` configuration so that you can run this command without a password instead.

Comment: Or, just require your script to be run by root in the first place, moving `sudo` out of the script and onto the command line if necessary to run the script as root.

Comment: Take a look at askubunt, this could answer your question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/57620/getting-an-authentication-token-manipulation-error-when-trying-to-change-my-us